# Ancho de td en una tabla Bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Porque el ancho de un `<td>` es demasiado grande comparado con el texto que contiene,los datos los cargo atraves de AJAX.
Estoy utilizando Bootstrap 4.

```
    <table class="table tabla_materiales table-responsive d-flex justify-content-center" >

  <tr><th>Usuario</th><th>Clave</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Apellido</th><th>Cedula</th><th>Provincia</th><th>Correo</th><th>Opciones</th></tr>

</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Utiliza el inspeccionar elemento de los navegadores, es una herramienta poderosa y te dirá que reglas **CSS** están interviniendo sobre ese elemento y podrás ver cual de las múltiples clases que tiene tu tabla es la que le está dando esas dimensiones no deseadas.

Comment: La tabla tiende, al agregar la clase table, a ocupar todo el ancho de la página. Por lo que esta se extenderá hasta conseguirlo, veo un scroll horizontal creado, eso no es normal ya que no debe crear el scroll horizontal con espacio suficiente para no hacerlo. Analiza con el inspector de tu navegador el padding y margin que se están creando entre los elementos <td></td> de tu HTML. Si no te interesan puedes quitarlos desde tu CSS. ¿Puede que la clase tabla_materiales creada por ti, modifique el comportamiento por defecto de la tabla?

Comment: El scroll horizontal se crea automaticamente,creo porque tengo muchas columnas.Pero no se como evitar ese espacio muy grande que se crea entre los <td>

Comment: El ancho de cada celda es idéntico, eso y que se vea el scroll horizontal, da la sensación de que tienes un ancho fijo en alguno de los elementos dentro de la tabla. Repasa todos los estilos y ojo con la herencia.